# Does Microsoft Security Essentials work with Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2?

Tags: anti-virus, compatibility, windows-server-2003, ms-security-essentials

Does Microsoft Security Essentials work with Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2?

I currently have AVG Business Edition, but it's close to expiring. I don't want to pay $189 a year, but I also don't want to uninstall it and screw around with MSE just to find out that it doesn't work, and then have to crawl back to AVG 9.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm 99% certain that MSE won't install on any of the Server products.

[System Requirements:](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/resources.aspx?mkt=en-us&s=1#mainNav)

> **Minimum system requirements for
>   Microsoft Security Essentials**
>
> Operating System: Genuine Windows XP
>   (Service Pack 2 or Service Pack 3);
>   Windows Vista (Gold, Service Pack 1,
>   or Service Pack 2); Windows 7

Comment: +1 You are correct.  You can change it to 100%.  :)

Comment: has anyone tried?
sometimes they say but it does anyway. (as for right now im just not going to F with it) but thanks

Comment: I've tried. It won't.

Comment: Just installed MSE version 2.0.657.0 on Server 2003 standard SP2.

Comment: JC: Things have changed a bit (including major version release and licensing) since this answer was posted :-)  Thanks for the update!

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: And almost 3 years later someone decided to give it a downvote with no comment. THAT's what makes this site so special :-p

Comment: @Chris_K Please read the previous comments and update your answer accordingly.

Comment: As of 6/2013, still works on 2003, downloaded "xp" version, and it's running fine.

Answer (score 11):

Since the version 2.0 release of Microsoft Security Essentials it will install on:

> - Windows Server 2008 R2
> - Windows Server 2008
> - Windows Home Server 2011

No official announcement was made however it will now safely install and the server check has been removed from the latest installer.

Comment: No server 2003 in that list, though. It does work, but is it really supported?

Comment: I've just downloaded and installed on Server 2003, and it appears to be working fine.  I doubt it's actually 'supported', heck, I can't even get the download page to work in IE6 that's installed, needed to install FF to get the download :)